# Why the weather prediction started from the first date output?

Tags: java

So I'm making a group project which is Java console GUI. This is my code for the Java console GUI:
Here's the output from my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class WeatherPredictionGUI extends JFrame {
    private final JTextArea textArea;
    private final JButton startButton;
    private final JButton stopButton;
    private ScheduledExecutorService executorService;
    private volatile boolean isPredicting;
    private Calendar currentDate;

    public WeatherPredictionGUI() {
        setTitle("Weather Prediction");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        textArea = new JTextArea(15, 40);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        startButton = new JButton("Start Prediction");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        startPrediction();
}
});

        stopButton = new JButton("Stop Prediction");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        stopPrediction();
}
});
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(startButton);
        buttonPanel.add(stopButton);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void startPrediction() {
        isPredicting = true;
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);

        currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::generatePrediction, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private void stopPrediction() {
        isPredicting = false;
        executorService.shutdown();
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void generatePrediction() {
        if (!isPredicting) {
            executorService.shutdown();
            return;
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            String prediction = generateRandomPrediction();
            String formattedDate = getCurrentDate();
            textArea.append(formattedDate + " - " + prediction + "\n");

            currentDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        });
    }

    private String generateRandomPrediction() {
        String[] weatherConditions = {"Sunny", "Cloudy", "Rainy", "Stormy"};
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(weatherConditions.length);
        return "Prediction: " + weatherConditions[randomIndex];
    }

    private String getCurrentDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd (EEEE)");
        return dateFormat.format(currentDate.getTime());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new WeatherPredictionGUI());
    }
}
```

[image]

When I click the Start Prediction it started from today date, but when i press stop and start prediction again it start at 16, i want it to continue from the last date which is 18 into 19.

Can somebody help me what i missing from my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the `currentDate` field every time the `startPrediction()` method is called. If you want to "continue" your prediction once you stop it, you don't want to reset this value back again to the current date. A simple `if()` check will do.

```
private void startPrediction() {
    isPredicting = true;
    startButton.setEnabled(false);
    stopButton.setEnabled(true);

    if (currentDate == null) {
        // never called before, initialize it to "today"
        currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    } else {
        // set and used before, so don't change it and reuse it.
    }
    executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::generatePrediction, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you stop and restart your weather prediction, it restarts from the first date (the current date) since you reset the `currentDate` variable in the `startPrediction` method. So, you can try in this way.

first, Store the last predicted date. Instead of resetting `currentDate` to the current date in `startPrediction`, store the last predicted date somewhere before stopping the prediction

For example: Assign the current `currentDate` value to `lastPredictedDate` before calling `executorService.shutdown()` in `stopPrediction`.

Then, instead of setting `currentDate` to the current date in `generatePrediction`, use the value stored in `lastPredictedDate`